# How many bird strikes are there per year? Any world-wide statistics?

Tags: safety

Does anyone know where I could find where the highest rates of bird strikes are?

Along the same lines, other wildlife, such as moose or bears on runways?

Comment: Have you checked http://wildlife.faa.gov/ ?

Comment: In collating any bird strike data, one must recognise that there is a tendency towards under reporting, especially when such strikes did not cause any damage. That said this report provides data for the UK & Canada  till 2009 https://easa.europa.eu/system/files/dfu/Final%20report%20Bird%20Strike%20Study.pdf

Comment: [IATA reports](http://www.skybrary.aero/bookshelf/books/3049.pdf) provide the % of in-flight accidents, and the ratio of bird strikes among them. Incidents are not included though, and this is only for commercial flights.

Comment: For airliners , GA or both?

Answer (score 6):

**Bird Strikes Worldwide**

From [Hedayati, R., Sadighi, M., *Bird Strike*, 2016](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-08-100093-9.09993-3):

> According to currently available data, **it is estimated that a bird-strike event occurs once every 2000 flights** (Khan, Kapania & Johnson, 2010). Further analyses of bird-strike statistics have shown that only 20% of bird strikes are actually reported by aviation staff. This means that the extent of economic and human losses resulting from bird strike could be much higher than what is currently presumed (Chuan, 2006). Consequently, this suggests that conducting further indepth studies on how to better capture reliable bird-strike event statistics and formulating strategies and solutions
>   would be beneficial.

From [EASA, *Bird Strike Damage & Windshield Bird Strike - Final Report*, 2009](https://easa.europa.eu/system/files/dfu/Final%20report%20Bird%20Strike%20Study.pdf):

> It had been intended to use the International Civil Aviation Organization (ICAO) database of bird strike statistics as a prime source of bird strike information, giving details of worldwide bird strike incidents and accidents. However, despite the best endeavours of fera, Atkins and EASA, it was not possible to gain access to this source of information. Therefore the literature search does not include data from regions such as Asia and Australia. Reporting levels from these regions are low and it is likely that even with access to ICAO data, there would be limited useful information available beyond that already available from UK and USA/Canada sources. **It is estimated, based on previous fera Bird Management Unit experience, that the UK and USA/Canadian data obtained represents approximately 50% of all worldwide bird strike reports.** Also regions such as Russia, China and South
>   America do not routinely contribute data to the ICAO database.

**Wildlife Strikes in the United States of America**

From [FAA, *Wildlife Strikes to Civil Aircraft in the United States 1990-2014*, 2015](http://www.faa.gov/airports/airport_safety/wildlife/media/Wildlife-Strike-Report-1990-2014.pdf):

> **The number of strikes annually reported to the FAA has increased 7.4-fold from 1,851 in 1990 to a record 13,668 in 2014**. The 2014 total was an increase of 2,267 strikes (20 percent) compared to the 11,401 strikes reported in 2013. For 1990–2014, 156,114 strikes were reported. **Birds were involved in 96.9 percent of the reported strikes, terrestrial mammals in 2.2 percent, bats in 0.8 percent and reptiles in 0.1 percent.** Although the number of reported strikes has dramatically increased, the number of reported damaging strikes has actually declined since 2000. Whereas the number of reported strikes increased 127 percent from 6,009 in 2000 to 13,668 in 2014, the number of damaging strikes declined 24 percent from 764 to 581. While there was a 20 percent increase in reported strikes from 2013 to 2014, the number of damaging strikes declined 4 percent from 606 to 581. The decline in damaging strikes has been most pronounced for commercial aircraft in the airport environment (at <1,500 feet above ground level [AGL]). Damaging strikes have not declined for general aviation (GA) aircraft.

From [Hedayati, R., Sadighi, M., *Bird Strike*, 2016](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-08-100093-9.09993-3):
According to the FAA, there were approximately 11'500 bird strikes in the US in the year 2014.

**Bird Strikes in Australia**

From [Hedayati, R., Sadighi, M., *Bird Strike*, 2016](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-08-100093-9.09993-3):

> **A significant proportion of all occurrences [...] involve aircraft striking wildlife, especially birds** (Bureau, 2009). According to a report (Australian aviation wildlife strike statistics: 2004-2013) providing aviation bird strike and animal strike occurrence data, **reported bird strikes have increased from 1085 in 2004 to 1751 in 2011**. The Australian aviation industry experienced a reduction in reported bird strikes in 2012 relative to 2011.
>   Among the **1568 reported bird strikes [...] in the year 2013**, [...]

**Bird Strikes in Brazil**

From [Hedayati, R., Sadighi, M., *Bird Strike*, 2016](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-08-100093-9.09993-3):

> Brazil is one of the most suffered countries from bird strike because it has the world’s second largest aircraft fleet as well as the world’s second largest number of bird species. [...]
>   The annual number of reported bird strikes has increased from 235 in 1993 to 587 in 2004.

**Bird Strikes in the Czech Republic**

From [Hedayati, R., Sadighi, M., *Bird Strike*, 2016](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-08-100093-9.09993-3):

> In the period 1993–1999, the data relating to 165 collisions was entered into the Czech Air Force’s database.

**Bird Strikes in France**

From [Hedayati, R., Sadighi, M., *Bird Strike*, 2016](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-08-100093-9.09993-3):

> The annual number of recorded bird-strike events in France exceeds 700, [...] (2008) [...]

**Bird Strikes in Iran**

From [Hedayati, R., Sadighi, M., *Bird Strike*, 2016](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-08-100093-9.09993-3):

> Within the years 1996–2011, 271 bird collisions in 32 airports were registered by Iran’s Civil Aviation Organization (CAO).

**Bird Strikes in Saudi Arabia**

From [Kutbi, N., *Bird Strike*, 2014](http://www.icao.int/MID/Documents/2014/Wildlife%20and%20FOD%20Workshop/Risk%20Reduction%20program%20-%20GACA.pdf):

> 30 in 2011, 19 in 2012, 37 in 2013

**Bird Strikes in the United Kingdom**

From [Hedayati, R., Sadighi, M., *Bird Strike*, 2016](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-08-100093-9.09993-3):

> The total number of reported strikes in the UK has increased from 608 in 1991 to 2365 in 2011: [...]

Answer (score 0):

This graphic shows trends on birdstrikes to civil aircraft
[image: trends on birdstrikes to civil aircraft]

Comment: This graph does not have sources.

Comment: Sorry, FAA and USDA publication. January 2019.